# Pull to refresh and Alamofire using Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to get data from a web URL(JSON). I am trying to implement pull to `RefreshControl` into my project. I have done it but don't know if it is correct or if the data is getting updated when refreshed. My code is:

```
var refresh = UIRefreshControl()

refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

func refreshData() {

    Alamofire.request("https://www.example.com/api").responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in
        self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!)
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refresh.endRefreshing()


    })        
}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing correctly but you need reload `tableView` and stop `UIRefreshControl` on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refresh.endRefreshing()             
}
```

**Note:** Instead of setting `separatorStyle` always on API request you need to set it once with `viewDidLoad` or with Interface builder.

Comment: So where abouts would I put this Nirav?

Comment: Same place where you are currently reloading tableView, simply add that two line in main thread.

Comment: Nirav, does all the above code including mine have to go in the `override func viewDidLoad() { super.viewDidLoad()` ?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` you need to set just this line         `self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.singleLine`