# Reloading TableView After calling Firebase Observer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called, after running print statements. Have figured out my tableView is not reloading... Have tried several spots, and still not reloading. Anyone know why?`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_USERS.child(CURRENTUSER!).child("cart").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print("check")
        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {

            self.cartItems = []

            for snap in snapshot {

                let shoeId = snap.key

                DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_SHOES.child("upcomingShoes").child(shoeId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let shoeData = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let shoe = Shoe(shoeId: shoeId, shoeData: shoeData)
                        print(shoe.shoeName)
                        self.cartItems.append(shoe)

                    }
                })
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
    print(self.cartItems.count)
}
```

//TO ADD TO MY DATABASE:

```
    @IBAction func addToCartPressed(_ sender: Any) {

            //Under the current users, child node called "cart", I want to add the current shoes id

            let currentUserCartRef = DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_USERS.child(CURRENTUSER!).child("cart")

            let shoeDataToAdd = [shoe.shoeId: true]

            currentUserCartRef.updateChildValues(shoeDataToAdd)


        }

`
```

Table View Cell Methods

```
//Table View Methods
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cartItems.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let shoe = cartItems[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cartCell", for: indexPath) as? CartCell {

        if let shoeImage = MainVC.imageCache.object(forKey: shoe.shoeImageUrl as NSString) {

            cell.configureCell(shoe: shoe, shoeImage: shoeImage)
        }
        else {

            cell.configureCell(shoe:shoe)
        }
        return cell

    }
    else {
        return PreviewCell()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a vairalbes at the top of my class:     var cartItems = [Shoe]()

Comment: That print statement is executed before the execution of line `self.tableView.reloadData()`. So it is obvious that it print `0` as output. Also you need to reload tableView on main thread.

Comment: Hey, ya i was just trying different areas to see if the code was running, the print statements arent running there or where the self.tableView.reloadData() either

Comment: @NiravD How would I go about calling reload on the main thread?

Comment: It should be like `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }`

Comment: Hey that worked! I will look more into how it worked, thanks for the help nirav

Comment: The request you have made with Firebase will work asynchronously, so when you get response you are on background so you need to make UI changes on the main thread.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pull to refresh and Alamofire using Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786546/pull-to-refresh-and-alamofire-using-swift-3)

Comment: I notice when I add to my database, the tableView Doesnt reload again? Where should I be called the tablviewreload?

Comment: Can you show the code that you are trying when adding data in firebase.

Comment: `@IBAction func addToCartPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        
    let currentUserCartRef = DataService.ds.DATABASE_REF_USERS.child(CURRENTUSER!).child("cart")
        
        let shoeDataToAdd = [shoe.shoeId: true]
        
        currentUserCartRef.updateChildValues(shoeDataToAdd)
        
        
    }`

Comment: You need to edit your question, Don't add code in comment edit your question and add code there not here

Comment: Sorry it is added now

Comment: Try to put break point in observer code and check it is getting called or not when you update the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
}
possibly it is returning 0 row for your table view cell. You must return number of rows greater than 0 to reload your tableview cell.

Comment: Hey, I updated my code to show my tableView methods. The problem I am having is it is not reloading the data. I was able to fix it by running it on the main thread, now I am having trouble reloading the data when the database is update

Comment: Have you checked cartItem array have efficient data in table view delegate methods(numberOfRows and cellForIndexPath) after updating database.